# Multi-Input Multi-Output in Genetic algorithm (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a GA program with python with 1 input, output and it works fine. But I want to find a solution with more input and output but I don't know how.

[Example from https://pygad.readthedocs.io/:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YFv9GSKqmw9X4QnH_vSnO7FPslPBGE0x/view?usp=sharing)

Given function: `y = f(w1:w6) = w1x1 + w2x2 + w3x3 + w4x4 + w5x5 + 6wx6`
with
`input(x1:x6)=(4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7)` and `y=44`

`solution = (w1:w6)`

But I want to find a solution with more input and output like `input1 = (1,5,-3,5,-1,-4)`, `y1 = 50`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io).

You can find the example you are looking for at [this script](https://github.com/ahmedfgad/GeneticAlgorithmPython/blob/master/example.py). Here is the code:

```py
import pygad
import numpy

"""
Given the following function:
    y = f(w1:w6) = w1x1 + w2x2 + w3x3 + w4x4 + w5x5 + 6wx6
    where (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)=(4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7) and y=44
What are the best values for the 6 weights (w1 to w6)? We are going to use the genetic algorithm to optimize this function.
"""

function_inputs = [4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7] # Function inputs.
desired_output = 44 # Function output.

def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    # Calculating the fitness value of each solution in the current population.
    # The fitness function calulates the sum of products between each input and its corresponding weight.
    output = numpy.sum(solution*function_inputs)
    # The value 0.000001 is used to avoid the Inf value when the denominator numpy.abs(output - desired_output) is 0.0.
    fitness = 1.0 / (numpy.abs(output - desired_output) + 0.000001)
    return fitness

fitness_function = fitness_func

num_generations = 100 # Number of generations.
num_parents_mating = 10 # Number of solutions to be selected as parents in the mating pool.

# To prepare the initial population, there are 2 ways:
# 1) Prepare it yourself and pass it to the initial_population parameter. This way is useful when the user wants to start the genetic algorithm with a custom initial population.
# 2) Assign valid integer values to the sol_per_pop and num_genes parameters. If the initial_population parameter exists, then the sol_per_pop and num_genes parameters are useless.
sol_per_pop = 20 # Number of solutions in the population.
num_genes = len(function_inputs)

init_range_low = -2
init_range_high = 5

parent_selection_type = "sss" # Type of parent selection.
keep_parents = -1 # Number of parents to keep in the next population. -1 means keep all parents and 0 means keep nothing.

crossover_type = "single_point" # Type of the crossover operator.

# Parameters of the mutation operation.
mutation_type = "random" # Type of the mutation operator.
mutation_percent_genes = 10 # Percentage of genes to mutate. This parameter has no action if the parameter mutation_num_genes exists or when mutation_type is None.

last_fitness = 0
def callback_generation(ga_instance):
    global last_fitness
    print("Generation = {generation}".format(generation=ga_instance.generations_completed))
    print("Fitness    = {fitness}".format(fitness=ga_instance.best_solution()[1]))
    print("Change     = {change}".format(change=ga_instance.best_solution()[1] - last_fitness))
    last_fitness = ga_instance.best_solution()[1]

# Creating an instance of the GA class inside the ga module. Some parameters are initialized within the constructor.
ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop,
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       init_range_low=init_range_low,
                       init_range_high=init_range_high,
                       parent_selection_type=parent_selection_type,
                       keep_parents=keep_parents,
                       crossover_type=crossover_type,
                       mutation_type=mutation_type,
                       mutation_percent_genes=mutation_percent_genes,
                       on_generation=callback_generation)

# Running the GA to optimize the parameters of the function.
ga_instance.run()

# After the generations complete, some plots are showed that summarize the how the outputs/fitenss values evolve over generations.
ga_instance.plot_result()

# Returning the details of the best solution.
solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
print("Parameters of the best solution : {solution}".format(solution=solution))
print("Fitness value of the best solution = {solution_fitness}".format(solution_fitness=solution_fitness))
print("Index of the best solution : {solution_idx}".format(solution_idx=solution_idx))

prediction = numpy.sum(numpy.array(function_inputs)*solution)
print("Predicted output based on the best solution : {prediction}".format(prediction=prediction))

if ga_instance.best_solution_generation != -1:
    print("Best fitness value reached after {best_solution_generation} generations.".format(best_solution_generation=ga_instance.best_solution_generation))
```

If you have any questions, please let me know!

Comment: Your PyGAD is truly awesome. Thanks. I believe the name came from your name ;)

Comment: Thanks too much dear :)
I did not deliberately selected the name PyGAD at the beginning. Here is how the name PyGAD came from:
1. When I was selecting a name for the library, I started by **PyGA** but there was a library of that name. I thought how to add another letter so that it is not far away from PyGA and also serves the purpose. 
2. Because I designed the library initially to only support **decimal genetic algorithm**, I added the letter **D** at the end and the name became **PyGAD**. 
3. A few moments later, I noticed that this is my last name :) Cool!